# Best practices to be followed by Configuration management & Build Engineers

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, configuration-management

I have been working on SCM for seven months, opted Visual SVN  as server and tortoise svn as client.So far i completed my seven months of journey in managing the ERP Application configuration management. I want to know whether i am following the best practices : have following doubts :

```
Project -------> Branches, trunk, tags.
```

1. Is it necessary to create a branch for a specific task (So far i am not following this process )
2. Added the base project to branch & after several commits with in the same day build the application, if any build issues trace the issue by monitoring application logs and closing the issues.
3. If more tasks has been committed major release eg. 1.0, 2.0 if minor 1.1, 2.1, 2.2 etc and adding major release project code snapshot in tags.
4. Allowing developers to commit on the branch, creating a checkout copy in test server, build the application, updating the recent commits to checkout copy in test server using svn update and build the application.

This is the mechanism I'm following, please give your valuable comments and suggestions if this process is  wrong.                       .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first question:

> Is it necessary to create a branch for a specific task.

This pattern is called "stable Trunk" - because all unstable stuff is done in the branches and only the stable stuff is merged in the Trunk. The opposite (use the trunk for development) is called "unstable Trunk".

Anyway: there is a stack overflow question: [Best branching strategy when doing continuous integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597707/best-branching-strategy-when-doing-continuous-integration) that discuss this theme.