# How to link continuous integration to my latest sprint trunk?

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, bazaar, externals

Using a continuous integration on my project, I need to checkout the code from **latest sprint** from BAZAAR as `bzr://path/to/myproject/sprint/123`

As this path is changing repeatedly (for each sprint), I'm currently using **externals** to create a `bzr://path/to/myproject/current` pointing to `bzr://path/to/myproject/sprint/123`.
So, I just need to change the externals to redirect the continuous integration tool to the latest project.

**Is there another way to do this ?**
What I don't want is to change the configuration of my project inside the continuous integration tool (CruiseControl.NET).

Comment: That depends on what CI tool are you using - can you please provide more details?

Comment: The CI used in CruiseControl.NET with BZR plugin.

Comment: The git version control provider for CCNet simply builds from the master branch - I assume you don't want that? Do you plan to build all branches that are available? That's an interesting problem, something like this was discussed for git plugin, but I don't think it ever got traction.

Comment: AT least, I would like to build each (active) iteration master branch, and on an extended use, yes, each branches for each iteration.

Comment: I've read through the Bazaar docs, but didn't find any reference to 'iteration'. Could you elaborate what it means in this context?

Comment: ho, it is like a sprint in agile development. Just a bunch of work identified with a number.

Comment: I don't understand ... do you have multiple sprints in progress at once?  Why create a separate branch for each one?  In other words: why not make "current" a real thing and just do the work there?  Actually I will suggest that as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option (might not be suitable for your teams' processes) would be to stop using a separate "sprint" location in bzr for each iteration's changes.  Instead, just use a "trunk" (or perhaps your "current" above).  If you are usually in a situation where you have multiple sprints having changes at the same time, then this would probably not be appropriate.

Comment: At first, the reply look strange, but then I start asking why a few times. Maybe this issue can be inverted, so main development is stored in the 'current' path, and push to a 'sprint/XYZ' path at the end. I will investigate !

Comment: Answer accepted! You just earn the reward. I will create **sprintA** for teamA, and **sprintB** for teamB, so only two CC.NET projects. thx !

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use a lightweight [checkout](http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/beta/en/user-guide/using_checkouts.html).

```
bzr checkout --lightweight bzr://path/to/myproject/iterations/123 bzr://path/to/myproject/current
```

You can then use `bzr switch` to switch to the next branch (I'm not sure if it will work over the network):

```
bzr switch -d bzr://path/to/myproject/current bzr://path/to/myproject/iterations/124
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't create a lightweight checkout over the network. If these are file:// URLs it should work though.

Answer (score 0):

After searching the web, I've found some articles about this question.

There are two solutions so far:

1. Automatically **detect newly finished branch** and build them. There is an example [here](http://codicesoftware.blogspot.com/2008/08/building-task-branches-with.html) using CC.NET. It is so applicable to my iterations.
2. Another way is to **provide scripts to developer** that execute most of the CI tool. This is not perfect, but this may detect issues before merging in the trunk.

Other references:
[Best branching strategy when doing continuous integration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597707/best-branching-strategy-when-doing-continuous-integration)