# switching svn working copy to commit to two different servers

Tags: svn, ubuntu

Good Day Stackoverflow

I have an SVN working copy of my admin system on my local machine.

The working copy is checked out from our production server. So any commits from me or my team mates make goes to the production server repo.

What I want to do is to create a repo with the production server code on our development server. So that me and my team mates can commit everything to the development box. when we are all happy with the code i want to switch my local repository over to commit to the production server

Is such a thing possible. If so... how?

Comment: Why can't u do with same repo and exporting them into different folders(I mean production, test or development)?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: Any particular reason why you have two different repos for development and production? Why not have one repo, and employ a [branching strategy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597707/best-branching-strategy-when-doing-continuous-integration) so that the production version of the system is in a special branch? Personally, I prefer feature branching, wherein "`trunk` is king" and is the branch from which one would release to production

Comment: You see my company doesn't want us to use branches. so the alternative strategy is to create a devbox repo and when the devbox code is stable i want to deploy that to live. The devbox sortof being a man in the middle when it comes to development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While using branches on the single server is more manageable way, you can have two repositories and switch between them, as requested

1. Create full dump of Production (`svnadmin dump PROD-PATH > DUMPFILE`)
2. Create DEVEL repo (`svnadmin create DEVEL-PATH`)
3. Load dump of PROD to DEVEL (`svnadmin load DEVEL-PATH --force-uuid < DUMPFILE`). `--force-uuid` **is mandatory** in order to have the same UUID in both repos (thus allowing to relocate single WC between repositories), "svnadmin create" assigned unique UUID to DEVEL
4. Relocate WCs to DEVEL
5. Code-commit-test...

In order to return code back to PROD

1. Get clean WC, updated to the DEVEL HEAD
2. Relocate WC to PROD
3. Update WC to the PROD HEAD, merge changes
4. Commit all changes accumulated from DEVEL in WC, as one "big bang" commit to PROD
5. Go to to part I, step 4

Comment: This is an awesome way to go but it seems like a lot of overhead when it comes to sending code to the production server...

Comment: @Ryan - yes, branches are The Natural Way (tm) in such cases

Answer (score 2):

Why does *production* have a version control system, but not the developers?

Version control is for the developers. You should be able to checkout, update, make changes in the code, add features, make mistakes, do stupid stuff, etc. It's what version control is for!

Production, if they get the code from the Subversion repository at all, should be checking out the code from a *tag*. A tag is what you want the world to see. It's something you hope has been purged of your mistakes, errors, and other bumblings through careful and rigorous testing.

Move your Subversion repository from Production, and put in into your development environment. That is, unless you mean production that it's being backed up and maintained -- Not that people who are on the production environment (like customers) actually use Subversion. In that case, let the repository stay in Production, but developers shouldn't be afraid to use it.

Some sites use *trunk* strictly for release code. This is not a good idea. Release code should be put into the *tags* directory. The trunk and branches are for the programmers to do *programming*.

Comment: I understand your answer. You see we are using http://www.springloops.io/ to host our production svn where our commits go to. I am not sure if we can make a repo on the dev box that can commit to springloops?

Comment: We managed to start using the branches. Thanks guys for the advice